# Fastest way to do sequential matrix multiplication in C

Tags: c, caching, optimization, memory, matrix-multiplication

I need to write a quick algorithm to perform matrix exponentiation in C. I have written both a recursive version and an iterative version of exponentiation by squaring. The matrices are not guaranteed to have eigenvalues. Here's my code:

(The matrix_multiply function has decent performance -- it's been optimized using SIMD and openMP, and the cache miss rate is relatively low.)

Iterative version

```
int matrix_power(matrix *result, matrix *mat, int pow) {
        matrix *temp;
        matrix *temp2;
        allocate_matrix(&temp, mat->rows, mat->cols);
        allocate_matrix(&temp2, mat->rows, mat->cols);
        initialize_to_identity(result);
        
        while (pow) {
            if (pow & 1) {
                copy_matrix(temp2, result)
                matrix_multiply(result, temp2, temp); //result = temp2 x temp
            }
            copy_matrix(temp2, temp);
            mul_matrix(temp, temp2, temp2);
            pow >>= 1;
        }
        destroy(&temp, mat->rows, mat->cols);
        destroy(&temp2, mat->rows, mat->cols);
        return 0;
}
```

Recursive version:

```
int matrix_power(matrix *result, matrix *mat, int pow) {
    matrix *temp;
    allocate_matrix(&temp, mat->rows, mat->cols);
    if (pow == 0) {
        initialize_to_identity(result);
        return 0;
    }
    if (pow == 1) {
        copy_matrix(result, mat);
        return 0;
    } else if (pow == 2) {
        matrix_multiply(result, mat, mat); //result = mat x mat
        return 0;
    }
    matrix_power(temp, mat, pow >> 1);
    matrix_multiply(result, temp, temp);
    if (pow & 1) {
       copy_matrix(temp, result); 
       matrix_multiply(result, temp, mat);
    }
    destroy(&temp, mat->rows, mat->cols);
    return 0;
}
```

Given a 1000 x 1000 matrix, the recursive version is 1.5 times faster than the iterative version. I think the reason might be that the iterative version is doing more copy than the recursive version. I tried to allocate 2 global temp array so that my recursive code won't need to allocate 2 temps in every call, but I hardly see any gain in performance. How can I change my code to gain better performance?